# i is an invalid keyword for this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, for school, we have to do a program that allows users to guess a number. I have the following code:

```
import random

my_number=random.randrange(100)
player_number=605
i=int(0)
while player_number!=my_number :
    player_number=int(input("Guess what number I am thinking of :"))
    if player_number<my_number:
        print("Too low")
    else:
        print("Too high")
    print("... Attemp", i=i+1) 
print("Right")
```

I get an error message saying that `'i' is an invalid function`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is your traceback?

Comment: `0` is already an `int`, so `int(0)` is redundant here.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here:

```
print("... Attemp", i=i+1)
```

the `print` function takes an arbitrary number of positional arguments and a small set of keyword arguments of the form `x = ...`.

`i` is not in that set of allowed keyword arguments.

maybe you meant:

```
print("... Attempt",i)
i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you're attempting to do, but assignment is a *statement* in Python, not an expression, so you can't use it inside `print`.  I'm guessing you want to do

```
print("Attempt", i)
i = i+1
```

Comment: I don't think that "assignment" is the problem here, although it would be in python2.x  where this would give a SyntaxError or something similar I'm guessing.

Comment: @mgilson: I think he's getting the keyword error because he tried to do an assignment inside a function call, not realizing that the syntax that does assignments is also the syntax for specifying keyword arguments.

Comment: Ahh... Ok, I'm tracking with your answer now.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from the following line:

```
print("... Attemp", i=i+1)
```

As far as I can tell, you are trying to do something like `i++` in other languages, where you both increment `i` and return the value from before the increment.

In Python, you cannot do this, put it on seperate lines:

```
print("... Attemp", i)
i += 1
```

The error is because `name=value` inside of a function call is the syntax for specifying a keyword argument, so for example you could call the following function using `foo(baz=2, bar=1)` and it would be equivalent to calling `foo(1, 2)`:

```
def foo(bar, baz):
    print('bar:', bar)
    print('baz:', baz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a feature "named parameters": when you can pass parameters by their names, and

```
print("... Attemp", i=i+1)
```

is exactly how it is done: the first `i` here becomes the name of the parameter to pass to `print`, but `print` does not understand such named parameter.